# How to interpret "and"

Tags: meaning

> Please be respectful to fellow employees, partners, and others who
>   work with or on behalf of XXX and **XXX’s legitimate business interests.**

In the example above, I am not sure if the bold part applies to "others".

I'm not sure which one is correct among two:

**(others who work with or on behalf of (XXX and XXX’s legitimate business interests))** - If I interpret this way, it also implies "others who work with XXX's legitimate business interest", and I think it sounds awkward

or

**(others who work with or on behalf of XXX) and (XXX’s legitimate business interests)** - I think this doesn't make sense, because the verb is "be respectful" and if I interpret this way, it becomes "be respectful to XXX's legitimate business interest", which sounds awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is asking you to be respectful of 3 groups of people:

1. fellow employees
2. partners
3. others who work with or on behalf of XXX and XXX’s legitimate business interests

It makes much more sense for `and XXX’s legitimate business interests` to refer to `others`.